# Angular5 not setting X-XSRF-TOKEN header

Tags: angular, cookies, angular5, csrf-protection

I've read through many solutions, but none have worked for me.

This github issue is essentially my problem (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20511)

I'm using Angular 5.2.5, Chrome Version 65.0.3325.146, Spring boot 1.5.4.

On my login form, I first send GET request to get the XSRF cookie. Then I send a post with Login info

[Send GET request that returns Set-Cookie header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plzcz.png)

[Send POST request and get 403](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3aX7.png)

Spring boot app configured with CSRF

```
        http
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
```

I'm using Angular webpack proxy so URL's are relative and sending requests with `withCredentials` options.

I've also tried writing my own interceptor as suggested in the Github issue, but i'm getting null when trying to get the token `let token = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string;` I've checked in Postman that the cookie has httpOnly flag set to false

Answer (score 2):

I have been having the same problem for a while. I've just fixed it with a bit of a hack

```
    // function to get cookie by name
    getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
            var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

getItemsFromServer(){

    let httpOptions={
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-XSRF-TOKEN': this.getCookie("XSRF-TOKEN")
                }),
                withCredentials: true
            };

    this.httpClient.get(url, httpOptions)
    .subscribe(response=>{
    // more code here
    }
    );
}
```